# Personalize .txt files with data taken from a .csv file. (Replacing variables)

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk, find, csv

I want to customize text files for a big list of people. The dirs and files are made already. For each person there are 6 text files. The 6 text files together contain 7 variables: `${FULLNAME}`, `${DOB}`, `${CITY}`, `${ZIP}`, `${STREET}`, `${EMAIL}` and `${ID}`.

Some variables are more frequent used than others. I need the variables in the text files to be replaced with data from a `.csv` file.

There are some fields in the header of `input.csv` that does not have a variable in the text files like `FIRSTNAME` and `NEW`, these field need to be ignored. None of the fields contain a comma.

This is an example of how `input.csv` looks like.

```
ID,FULLNAME,FIRSTNAME,EMAIL,DOB,CITY,ZIP,STREET,NEW
1.2;{1},John Example,John,info@example.com,01-01-1990,New York,00501,Street 1,yes
1.2;{2},Firstname Lastname,Firstname,firstname.lastname@domain.com,01-01-1980,Dallas,75227,Lane 2,no
```

In `input.csv` each person have his own row with data. Each person have his own dir with text files. We need to make sure the replaced variables match with the right person. I thought that the name of the directory can be an useful value to let the system know where to be. That made me take the e-mail addresses from `input.csv` and use it as directory name for each persons directory.

The file structure I have now you can see below. In the future I want to add more subdirectories and text files.

```
generate
├── documents
│   ├── firstname.lastname@domain.com
│   │   ├── dir1
│   │   │   ├── subdir1
│   │   │   │   └── text5.txt
│   │   │   ├── text1.txt
│   │   │   └── text6.txt
│   │   ├── dir2
│   │   │   └── text2.txt
│   │   ├── dir3
│   │   │   └── text3.txt
│   │   └── dir4
│   │       └── text4.txt
│   └── info@example.com
│       ├── dir1
│       │   ├── subdir1
│       │   │   └── text5.txt
│       │   ├── text1.txt
│       │   └── text6.txt
│       ├── dir2
│       │   └── text2.txt
│       ├── dir3
│       │   └── text3.txt
│       └── dir4
│           └── text4.txt
└── input.csv
```

example of text5.txt (other text files look similar)

```
ID: ${ID}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, "sed ${FULLNAME} eiusmod tempor" incididunt ${DOB} labore et dolore magna ${EMAIL}. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. {Duis aute irure dolor} in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

Lorem ${CITY}, ${ZIP}, {STREET}.
```

Expected output text5.txt

```
ID: 1.2;{1}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, "sed John Example eiusmod tempor" incididunt 01-01-1990 labore et dolore magna info@example.com. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. {Duis aute irure dolor} in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

Lorem New York, 00501, Street 1.
```

All the variables of the text files which are located in the dir firstname.lastname@domain.com and its subdirectories need to be replaced with John Example's data (input.csv). This also need to be done for info@example and hundreds of other persons.

It took me a long time to write this. I'm having a hard time trying to explain my needs as good as possible. I hope you guys understand my question and can help me realize this.

Comment: Have you looked into existing text templating engines?

Comment: @Kusalananda Yes, I found nothing constructive on github

Comment: This isn't a question about how to solve a specific problem, it's a job description. You might have more luck getting your job done by hiring someone on upwork.com or similar.

Comment: I did the whole job myself :) I will answer on my own question later